# Can out-of-spec rear camber on one side can cause the car to pull to that side while going straight?

Tags: honda, civic, steering, alignment, camber

I have a 01-05 Civic and it pulls noticeably to the right when my steering wheel is straight.

I did a full alignment ( we have a alignment bench where I work ) only the non-adjustable rear right camber is out-of-spec ( -1°47' for a specification between -1°30' and 0°00' ).

I swapped tyre positions multiple times in different configurations.

No observable play in suspension components.

The rear right wheel though seems to be more difficult to turn by hand, dunno if it's just the brakes or a bad bearing yet, could be my imagination.

Your opinions are very welcome.

Comment: Did someone slide it into the kerb in its history?

Comment: I don't have that information, there's no visible damage though

Comment: So a bent suspension component is the probable culprit.

Comment: Also, on the lower rear suspension piece (don't know what it's called) should be considered suspect ... I understand they wear out and cause issues. Might be worth it to do a visual check on all the bushings back there. You may not feel any slop in it because the suspension may be soaking it all up.